# Git merge and push

Tags: git, github, branch, push

I am starting with Git, so I feel that this question could be the newbiest question of day because this task is so simple, but it's causing a terrible headache..

I have 2 local branches:

- master
- local/production

And 2 remotes:

- master
- production

I need to pass local changes to production. So, my workflow was:

```
git checkout local/production
git merge master
git commit
git push
```

**git merge:**
Seems Work fine, it detected all differences.

**git commit:**

> On branch local/production
>
> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/production' by 2 commits.
>
> nothing to commit (working directory clean)

And **git push:**

> Everything up-to-date

So that's all, I couldn't push my changes to remote repository.

Comment: This is quite good. It sort of stops prematurely ( I'd like to have it to end in local removing subdir ) but otherwise good. https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Root cause:** To cut the explanation short, it appears to me that your `local/production` is not tracking `origin/production`. You can check this with `git branch -avv`.

**About `git push`**: Note that `git push` without arguments will update *all* the remote branches that have updated in your local tracking branches (from the `git-push(1)` manual page):

```
git push ...  [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

The special refspec : (or +: to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs git to
push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the
remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote
side. This is the default operation mode if no explicit refspec is found (that is
neither on the command line nor in any Push line of the corresponding remotes
file---see below).
```

Because the result of simple `git push` is sometimes little unexpected if forgotten what changes done in local branches, I personally like to explicitly specify which branches I want to push. In your case it seems this is what you want to do:

```
git push origin local/production:production
```

If you want `local/production` to track `origin/production`, you can make the `local/production` tracking branch for `origin/production` using option `-u`:

```
git push -u origin local/production:production
```

(only required once). Then you can pull from origin to `local/production`.

**Executive Summary:** you need to understand the concept of tracking branch and the peculiar semantics of `git push`.

**P.S.** I am wondering about your choice of your branch name `local/production` here. Why not just `production`? I am suspecting you already have `production` tracking `origin/production` and maybe use `local/production` for you local development. In this case a reasonable work flow is like this:

1. `git pull origin production:production` to pull the changes to your `production`
2. If there are new commits in `production`, that is `local/production` is behind then either rebase your `local/production` on `production` (or merge `production` on `local/production`)
3. the moment you want to push your changes, `merge` or `cherry-pick` your commits to `production` and push the changes with `git push origin production:production`.

Comment: You are right @FooF. My problem was that I didn't have linked (or tracked?) branch local/production. So, `git push` (without arguments) didn't detect this branch. Another solution was adding this to git config: `git config remote.origin.push local/prodcution:refs/heads/production`. Anywise I agree about explicitly specify which branches you want to push.