# Merge master with 2nd branch and commit to master

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm very new to Github and I've created a branch about 2 weeks ago. This branch is now final and I'd like to move those updated to my master.

I've tried reading up on the subject and found that I should do:

`git checkout master`

`git merge picto_gone` (The branch I'd like to merge)

This works fine and I see all the editted files and a 'fast-forward' thingie.

Now; If I go back to my github.com page I see that my master is still last updated * days ago. And not today or the last commit on my other branch for that matter.

If I try to commit it says my branch is ahead 6 commits.

Long story short: How do I merge my branch with my master so I can start using my master again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git pull
git push origin master
```

you must push your change to trunk.

Comment: It worked. But I'm not sure if I understand what happened. If I'm correct I merged my branches locally and since I'm in my master branche when I push it pushes the new locally(and merged) branch back to my master?

Comment: I think you may not understand the difference between `merge` and `push` and I see [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597494/git-merge-and-push) seems explain it well, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must send your local 'master' branch to github.

```
git push
```