# git merging: Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: git

I am new to git and been doing the following:

```
git checkout -b mybranch
...Make changes
git push origin mybranch
```

At this point I can see the mybranch branch on the remote server

Now I do:

```
git checkout master
git merge mybranch
```

Now I do not see the merged changes in my master on the remote and I usually do another push:

```
git push origin master
```

Is this the right way of going about it? I am not sure about the last push. No git tutorial I see talks about the step after the merge. So, I have a feeling I am not doing something right but not sure what.

Comment: Wouldn't pushing merge it?

Comment: That is what I think. It seems to work fine but the tutorials never talk about the last push. See for example: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: when I used github... I never used merge. I just used push and it merged it for me

Comment: Have a look at this [Stack Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597494/git-merge-and-push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are doing it correctly.

When you do:

```
git checkout master
git merge mybranch
```

...you are just merging the local `mybranch` into the local `master`.  You then need to push it to the remote.  To my knowledge, `git push` never does a merge under any circumstances.  If there was a conflict, then Git would let you know, and you would have to do a `git pull` (which will fetch the remote branches and attempt an automatic merge) followed by a `git push`.

Please note that the behavior of `git push` depends on your tracking branches and your configuration.  For example, depending on your configuration, the command `git push` without giving a branch-name may push all the local branches or just the current one to the remote.  By default, `git push` without arguments causes all the local tracking branches to be pushed to the remote repo.

For more information, `man git-push` is your friend.

Comment: By the way, you will likely need to use `git push -u origin mybranch` (notice the **-u**) to set your local `mybranch` as a tracking branch the first time you push it to the remote.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct.

`git checkout master`
`git merge mybranch`

These 2 commands basically merges the `mybranch` branch onto `master` branch. After merging, these changes are on your local repository only. To make those changes appear on the remote repository, you have to push those changes. You can do it by:

`git push origin branch_name`

which in your case becomes,
`git push origin master`